# need to find the consecutive rows where the status is AV prior to VL but receiving a missing SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, row, data-retrieval

I am trying to retrieve consecutive rows where the ls_status is appearing in this order per letter eg i want to see the entries where status 'AV' is occurring prior 'VL'

in my case i need to see rows 17 and 18 in my results set:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TALU5.png)

Below is the executed sql.
if i run both subqueries separately there is no problem but when i run the entire piece of code i receive error:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 35

Any idea why this is??

```
with ls_ital as
    (select ls_key, ls_letter, ls_status, ls_insertdate, row_number() over (order by ls_key) as id
    from letter_status_aital),
  t1 as  
    (select ls_key, ls_letter, ls_status, ls_insertdate,
    row_number() over(order by id) as rn,
    id -(row_number() over(order by id)) as diff
    from ls_ital
    where ls_status in ('AV','VL'));
```

i tried to run both subqueries separately and they succeed but when i run both i get the

ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 35

see the results of the 1st query:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9tPa.png)

i am not sure if i am on the right track with the query but i just need to retrieve rows 17 and 18 from the 1st screen shot that is when a status 'AV' occurs before 'VL' sequentially

Answer (score 3):

If you fix the syntax error in your code, which is using a sub-query factoring clause without a final `SELECT` clause that follows the sub-queries (which you can either append or convert your final sub-query to):

```sql
with ls_ital as (
  select ls_key,
         ls_letter,
         ls_status,
         ls_insertdate,
         row_number() over (order by ls_key) as id
  from   letter_status_aital
)
select ls_key,
       ls_letter,
       ls_status,
       ls_insertdate,
       row_number() over(order by id) as rn,
       id -(row_number() over(order by id)) as diff
from   ls_ital
where  ls_status in ('AV','VL');
```

Then your code is not going to do what you expect because you are not checking that `AV` comes before `VL` and you are not doing any filtering on `diff` to check that groups of consecutive rows are being returned.

---

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing which will be much simpler (and probably more efficient):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   letter_status_aital
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY ls_key
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( av vl )
  DEFINE
    av AS ls_status = 'AV',
    vl AS ls_status = 'VL'
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
create table letter_status_aital(
  ls_letter,
  ls_bydoctor,
  ls_status,
  ls_insertdate,
  ls_key
) AS
SELECT 1714, 1035, 'AP', DATE '2022-08-19', 4801 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1714, 1035, 'AV', DATE '2022-08-19', 4803 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1714, 1035, 'VL', DATE '2022-08-22', 4837 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1714, 1035, 'AP', DATE '2022-08-22', 4842 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1714, 1035, 'VL', DATE '2022-08-22', 4844 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| LS_KEY | LS_LETTER | LS_BYDOCTOR | LS_STATUS | LS_INSERTDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4803 | 1714 | 1035 | AV | 19-AUG-22 |
| 4837 | 1714 | 1035 | VL | 22-AUG-22 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cCiuLH4_)

Answer (score 0):

If that's *it* (I mean, query you posted is supposed to return result you want), either select from `t1`:

```
with ls_ital as
    (select ls_key, ls_letter, ls_status, ls_insertdate, row_number() over (order by ls_key) as id
    from letter_status_aital),
  t1 as  
    (select ls_key, ls_letter, ls_status, ls_insertdate,
    row_number() over(order by id) as rn,
    id -(row_number() over(order by id)) as diff
    from ls_ital
    where ls_status in ('AV','VL'))
select * from t1;
```

or get rid of it (as a CTE):

```
with ls_ital as
    (select ls_key, ls_letter, ls_status, ls_insertdate, row_number() over (order by ls_key) as id
    from letter_status_aital)
select ls_key, ls_letter, ls_status, ls_insertdate,
    row_number() over(order by id) as rn,
    id -(row_number() over(order by id)) as diff
    from ls_ital
    where ls_status in ('AV','VL');
```

Comment: your code works really well with the match_organize but if i want to put in a where clause to limit by date time i can not place it after the FROM clause.  Thank you in advance.